# Unable to access static member -> unresolved external symbol i

Tags: c++, static

```
class Test
{
private:
    static int i;
public: 
    static void foo()
    {
        i = 10;
    }
    static int geti(){ return i; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    Test::foo();
    std::cout << Test::geti();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple test, I think I am wrong about static use in my program. Because I always get "Unresolved external symbol i". Why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *define* `static` member variables outside class definition:

```
int Test::i=10; //or any value or just the definition will do.
```

In class you are just *declaring*, not defining. Without a definition, linker will not be able to find it ans will show *unresolved external symbols*.

`static` member variables in a class requires this special treatment because of [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) and compilation model of C++.